# How can I capture altitude on an Android phone?

Tags: android, geolocation, altitude

I want to be able to capture altitude in my Android app.  I know I can use GPS for where I am, but is there any way I can derive roughly how high the phone is off the ground using a combination of sensors?  If not, what is the closest estimation I can get?

Comment: Answered pretty decently over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995998/android-get-altitude-by-longitude-and-latitude

Comment: I'm asking as if I were in a helicopter, not on land.  Though, that explains half the problem.

Comment: Ah. In that case you really do need the 3D fix Z-axis from the GPS chip. I've seen that work on the iPhone, although it's never really accurate. It often reports my current height as some 300m above sea level while I live in the Netherlands at about 3m below sea level. Don't know about Android, maybe the SDK just discards any available alt info b/c it's too inaccurate anyway...

Comment: @Mels Thank you! I didn't know GPS chips had Z-axis available, even if they are that horrible at finding your location. :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the phone has a barometric pressure sensor, you can use SensorManager.getAltitude to get the altitude based on a pressure reading.  This method also requires the current pressure at sea level, which can either be obtained from local airport data (via a web service) or approximated with SensorManager.PRESSURE_STANDARD_ATMOSPHERE.

For more, see:

[Android: How to use SensorManager.getAltitude(float p0, float p)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411114/android-how-to-use-sensormanager-getaltitudefloat-p0-float-p)